# QGIS Save location and information to Excel file

Tags: qgis

I have georeferenced an old map in QGIS and want to save the location of a place and then be able to type information about that captured location (owner, acreage etc) in a table.

I am an historical geographer struggling to learn QGIS so apologies if I have missed an already answered query - I did try and check.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a new point vector layer, and add attribute columns for each of the items of information you want. Then start editing that layer, and click on the map at the place of interest. Then a form will pop up where you can enter the information.

You create a new layer with `Layer->Create Layer`. The default format for vectors is geopackage, but you can choose the older, more popular shapefile.

If you choose to create a polygon layers for your places of interest instead of points, then you can add two columns to the polygon attribute table for X and Y (longitude and latitude) coordinates, and then populate them in the QGIS "Field Calculator" with the expressions:  `x(centroid($geometry))` and `y(centroid($geometry))`.  Just be aware that a geometric centroid will not necessarily fall inside a polygon (Imagine a "C" shaped area).

Comment: I was afraid you might say that. I have been adding polygons with attributes and I was hoping I could utilise the pkuid to extract a lat and longitude without needing to add a further points layer. Is it not possible to do that?

Comment: The pkuid will not help (no location information there) but you can easily extract long and lat from the polygons **centroid** if that's what you want . I have edited the answer with this additional detail.

Comment: That’s brilliant that worked really well. Can I ask quick extra query. In the attribute table how do you edit the column titles/field names please? I have looked and can’t find an answer for QGIS 3  The answers seem to refer to a Table Manager plug in which no longer seems available. Once again thanks for your help.

Comment: You might want to post a new question to get full answers. AFAIK currently in the Processing tools, there is the "Refactor Fields" tool to rename attribute columns.

Comment: Thanks I’ll do that.  I tried the Refactor Fields but it created a scratch file and didn’t seem to save. Bit confusing.

Comment: You can save the scratch file (right click on the layer name > export). Or you can insert a file path and file name when you run the refactor fields tool, and it will create a non-temporary layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract polygon centroid to create points.  The point sampling tool could help query the information in your polygons.  You can also do a spatial query (join attributes by location) in the processing toolbox (plugin).   To save to Excel, you can export to wkt.  That will be a csv file that you can import to Excel.